# Program cannot resolve host name if it's started before first successful internet connection

Tags: python, internet, pppd

This is related to [a stackoverflow post I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35630081/cant-resolve-url-until-program-is-restarted).

Basically I have a Python script that I'm running on an embedded system (Buildroot-based). The python script runs on startup, but I cannot guarantee that the internet connection will be up by then (based on pppd), because the unit might not be in an area with mobile phone signal.

What I've found is that if the python code starts before an internet connection has been established on the machine, even after the connection is established, the python code is still unable to resolve names. I get a `[Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution` error when the socket tries to connect. The only way I can get it to work is to establish the internet connection at least once before I start the python code.

What changes are being made to the system after the internet connection is established at least once that the Python code could be looking for? Is there something I can set up on boot up so that this does not happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most programs read the system DNS configuration (in `/etc/resolv.conf`) only once when they start up or when they make their first network access. They don't re-read the configuration if it changes.

It appears that on your system, the DNS configuration changes when the network goes up (probably changes from unconfigured to having DNS servers configured). This is very common, and unavoidable if the system isn't always connected to the same network.

A way to ensure that programs won't be affected is to run a local DNS caching server. This way, the DNS configuration for applications can be static (always `nameserver 127.0.0.1` in `/etc/resolv.conf`), and only the DNS caching server needs to be told about the servers provided by the network connection. [Dnsmasq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnsmasq) is a common choice, especially on embedded systems (if you have a Linux router, it probably runs dnsmasq). If you're building your own image with Buildroot, include the `dnsmasq` package. If you have a pre-built image without dnsmasq, installing dnsmasq via Builtroot may still be the best bet but I'm not familiar with Buildroot so I can't explain how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - this explains the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You may use the script hooks that pppd provides, to call your script after ip is up. For instance (from pppd manpage)

```
/etc/ppp/ip-up
A program or script which is executed when the link is available for 
sending and receiving IP packets (that is, IPCP has come up). It is 
executed with the parameters 

interface-name tty-device speed local-IP-address remote-IP-address ipparam
```

When you start your python script from inside there, you should be ok.

Comment: Great idea, I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 2):

To force a refresh of the resolve table, you can run this (on linux):

```
import ctypes
libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libc.so.6')
res_init = libc.__res_init
res_init()
```